# Dynamically adding view or inflating layout to RecyclerView's item

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a social network application in which I need to show feeds to subscribers.. for showing feeds in a list. I am using `RecyclerView`. No Problem till now... but the problem comes when I have to show some comments on the feed. I am trying to accomplish a layout similar to Instagram where they show an image and maximum 3-4 comments with it in the main list. I am getting Image links and its comments (in JSON array form) from server.. sometimes I get comment array size 0 and sometime 1/2../10. I have created an XML for the comment layout that contains 2 `TextView` and I am inflating it in `FeedViewHolder` based on my `ViewType`.. my `item_comment` look like

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/comment_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">

    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/indigo_500"
        android:id="@+id/comment_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/profile_pic"
        android:text="Somesh Kumar"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comment_name"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="This is a comment"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am passing my feed list to RecyclerView adaptor..and then I am checking if the item (that will be shown) should have the comments or not.

```
 @Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    FeedParser.DataClass dataClass = feedList.get(position);
    int ITEM_TYPE = 0;
    if (dataClass.getPost_type() == FEED_TYPE_PICTURE) // Feed item contains caption with pictures
    {
        // check if it has comments
        if (dataClass.getComments().size() == 0)
        {
            ITEM_TYPE = PICTURE_WITHOUT_COMMENTS;
        }
        else
        {
            ITEM_TYPE = PICTURE_WITH_COMMENTS;
        }
    }
    return ITEM_TYPE;
}
```

and passing `ITEM_TYPE` to `onCreateViewHolder` like

```
 @Override
public FeedViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
{
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_feed, parent, false);
    return new FeedViewHolder(itemView, viewType);
}
```

and in `FeedViewHolder` inflating item layout and comment layout if `viewType` has comments

```
        public FeedViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType)
    {
        super(itemView);
        tvFeedUsername = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFeedUsername);
        tvFeedCaption = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFeedCaption);


        switch (viewType)
        {
            // TODO: Write code for other feed type such as picture and video
            // viewType 1 = PICTURE_WITH_COMMENTS
            case 1:
                layoutComments = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layoutComments);
                commentView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_comment, null);
                postCommentText = (TextView) commentView.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
                postCommentName = (TextView) commentView.findViewById(R.id.comment_name);
                layoutComments.addView(commentView);
                break;
        }
    }
```

I have verified this works perfect but when i setText for `holder.postCommentName` & `holder.postCommentText` in `onBindViewHolder` it only set text for last comment ( i know it's because i am looping through all the comment and setting them one by one on the same `holder.postCommentText` and `holder.postCommentName` here is my onBindViewHolder..

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(FeedViewHolder holder, int position)
{
    FeedParser.DataClass feedModel = feedList.get(position);
    holder.tvFeedUsername.setText(feedModel.getName());
    holder.tvFeedCaption.setText(feedModel.getPost_status());

    if (getItemViewType(position) == TEXT_WITH_COMMENTS)
    {
        for (int commentNum = 0; commentNum < feedModel.getComments().size(); commentNum++)
        {
            holder.postCommentName.setText(feedModel.getComments().get(commentNum).getUser_name());
            holder.postCommentText.setText(feedModel.getComments().get(commentNum).getComment());
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know even if this is the right approach or not... but this is how some people wrote an answer here... like [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517988/adding-components-dynamically-to-recyclerview) . I have searched many SO post but not getting what I want. Is there any other way where I can inflate comment's XML layout and add it multiple time on RecyclerView 's item?

**Thanks any help would be much appreciated!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i Believe you need to create a nested recycler view in the main recycler view and you need to pass the data into the nested adapter as that of the comments .So basically 
 1.)Main Recycler View contains Caption , Image , RecyclerView for comments (as        per instagram)

2.)In the second reyclerview put your above comment layout and create a seperate adapter with data as comments

Thats It .. Ask me for any further help

Comment: child RecyclerView inside Main RecyclerView item ? Do you think its right in my case because i only need to show only last 3 comment and nothing else! Don't you this it's better to inflate a xml ? i really don't know how instagram or others are doing this.

Comment: If you have to loop through some items (in your case comments ) , you have to create a list or a reyclerView(recommended) to display them . Well i have experience with android development and i can tell you that this the way to go about it . Dont worry you will be fine

Comment: Sure .. Do let me know if that worked . All the Best !!1